# Media query aspect ratio with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, media-queries, phonegap-build, aspect-ratio

Client wants to have layout for the mobile app adjusted according to aspect ratio of screen:
http://screensiz.es/phone and not just some width/height breakpoints. They want for example to cover 3:5 and/or 9:16. So I'm using media queries for aspect ratio. I'm developing the app in jQuery Mobile and using PhoneGap Build for compiling.
I have consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567474/phonegap-css-media-queries-aspect-not-working) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186414/whats-the-algorithm-to-calculate-aspect-ratio-i-need-an-output-like-43-169) answer, but I can't detect right aspect ratios. Page: http://pavlov.rs/ht/index.html

When I open it in mobile browser on Samsung Galaxy S2 I get:

```
Dimensions = 320x229
Gcd = 1
Aspect = 320:229

Ratio is 32x45 (from media queries)
```

But when I compile that page with PhoneGap and open the app I get:

```
Dimensions = 320x508
Gcd = 4
Aspect = 80x127

Ratio is 32x45 (from media queries)
```

Is there some safe and bulletproof way working with those kind of media queries and specifically with jQM and PhoneGap combination?

Thanks.